# a fatal error in compiling a c++ program

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows

I am using eclipse kepler for C++, in compiling a simple hello world program I saw this error.

```
c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:73:20: fatal error: w32api.h: No such file or directory
```

while the whole windows is as bellow.

```
09:15:59 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project project1 ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\5.3.0\\include\\c++" "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\5.3.0\\include\\c++\\backward" "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\5.3.0\\include" "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\5.3.0\\include-fixed" "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\5.3.0\\include\\c++\\mingw32" "-IC:\\MinGW\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\project1.o" "..\\src\\project1.cpp" 
In file included from c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:53:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\src\project1.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:73:20: fatal error: w32api.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

09:16:01 Build Finished (took 2s.535ms)
```

what can I do?
my code is this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     cout<<"hello world";
}
```

Comment: this is my code  ---#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<<"hello world";
}

Answer (score 1):

In my case i've solved like this:

1. Go to MinGW Installation Manager.
2. Select "Basic Setup" from installation list and tick the package "mingw32-base-bin".
3. From the installation tab select "Apply Changes".

Answer (score 0):

the problem is related to the MinGW installer. there is a package that must be installed, but it didn't install it. go to the MinGW installer and add the ming-w32-w32.api and then apply changes from installation menu.